# MYSQL differs in Output from script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I have a problem with the MySQL output formatting while executing the commands from a bash script.

If I execute a command on the command line then, I am able to get the output in formatted as  expected.

```
$ mysql -u dbclient -pxxxx GEKONYLOGDB -e "select now(),max(time_stamp) from metrics"
+---------------------+---------------------+
| now()               | max(time_stamp)     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2012-12-09 14:25:38 | 2012-12-09 14:25:20 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

But where as if I keep the same command in a script and execute I am not getting the formatted output.

```
$ cat test
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u dbclient -pxxxx GEKONYLOGDB -e "select now(),max(time_stamp) from metrics"

$ ./test
now()   max(time_stamp)
2012-12-09 14:27:52     2012-12-09 14:27:47
```

So all I need the same output from script.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pass the `-t` or `--table` option to force table output.

```
mysql --table -u dbclient -pxxxx GEKONYLOGDB -e "select now(),max(time_stamp) from metrics"
```

From `mysql --help`:

```
  -t, --table         Output in table format.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, It is working and giving the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have --table option enabled by default when calling mysql program, please check this SO answer [How to store MySQL results to a file in table format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58395334/565525).