# How to store MySQL results to a file in table format

Tags: mysql, formatting, batch-processing

I am trying to create a file and store in it the results from my query. I have a batch file that contains the single query,

```
USE database1;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "abc" INTO OUTFILE output.txt;

QUIT
```

Executing this batch file using,

```
mysql -u root -p -t -vvv < select.sql
```

However, the result is not table formatted and fields' names are missing from the top.

```
100 abc Brown 32
101 abc Flair 25
102 abc McDonald 45
.
.
.
```

If I remove the INTO OUTFILE statement and print the results on terminal, then is working OK.

```
+----+------+---------+-----+
| id | name | surname | age |
+----+------+---------+-----+
| 100| abc  | Brown   |   32|
| 101| abc  | Flair   |   25|
| 102| abc  | McDonald|   45|
+----+------+---------+-----+
```

How can I achieve the above in a txt file?

**UPDATE**

Special thanks to GreyBeardedGeek. Here is the solution for this question with help of GreyBeardedGeek.

Batch file:

```
USE database1;

SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = "abc";

QUIT
```

and mysql client:

```
mysql -u root -p -t -vvv < select.sql > output.txt
```

Comment: remove the INTO outfile, and then do: mysql -u root -p -t -vvv < select.sql > output.txt

Comment: OK! Well...I lost my mind here! Is working, but why? What's the difference? Thank's a lot :)

Comment: INTO OUTFILE changes the default output, though it has options for quoting values, line delimiters, etc.

Comment: So, INTO OUTFILE, is useful if you want to store a csv file for example. And choose the delimiter symbols etc. I'm correct?

Comment: yes, it's usually used to get either CSV or TSV (Tab Delimited) output

Comment: One more thing .. My output result has the sql query on top. There is any way to remove it? Any flag for this?

Comment: if you're on Linux, pipe the result through sed '1 d', e.g. mysql -u root -p -t -vvv < select.sql | sed '1 d' > output.txt

Comment: Either you or @GreyBeardedGeek should post this as an answer and then you should accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
mysql -u root -p -t -vvv < select.sql | sed '1 d' > output.txt
```

Comment: What's the `sed '1 d'` part do?

Comment: It removes the first line of the output, which in this case, is the sql query

Comment: I'm guessing the `-t` option causes the output to be in a table format, but what does `-vvv` do?

Comment: -vvv activates "verbose" mode

Answer (score 0):

You can also do following:

```
mysql -uroot -p DatabaseName -t -e "select * from table" > file.txt
```

This doesn't need to make an SQL file and then filter out the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Besides using mysql client program options (mysql --help) one can configure defaults within .my.cnf file. Example (MacOs, Linux) to enable --table option:

edit/create a file:

```
vim ~/.my.cnf
```

add/update:

```
[client]
table
```

next time you call mysql command line program it will use options from .my.cnf file producing output in table format, e.g. the same as one has called:

```
mysql ... --table ...
```

Please note that command line options override options from the .my.cnf files.

References:

- call `mysql --help` for list of options
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html